# Switching supply component selection

Tags: current, switch-mode-power-supply

I am making a charger using a switching power supply.
Output is 5A at 5VDC.
Input is 220V AC which is converted into DC voltage using diodes and then converted to 5V by the transformer and switching circuitry.

Below is an example-only diagram.

[image: block diagram]

Image source: [Rohm - Tech Web, AC-DC Basics, Transformer vs Switching](https://techweb.rohm.com/product/power-ic/acdc/acdc-basic/12620/)

Question: If my output current is 5A then do all of the components need to be 5A rated, including the diodes and transistors on the input side of the transformer, or can they be rated at less than 5A because the input current is less due to the input voltage being much higher than the output voltage

Comment: This isn't a great question and it's difficult to answer well. You should edit this to include much more details - input voltage, output voltage, any particular load needs, what converter you plan to use/design. Also, things like block diagrams or schematics (better) will help explain what you're doing and what your questions is. Show where you design has currently got to.

Comment: What is the input and output voltage?

Comment: A buck converter does not use a transformer. It does use an inductor, which has to pass the output current. The average input current of a buck is less than the output current, consisting of periods of the output current, and periods with zero input current. An input capacitor averages these to less than the output current.

Comment: What's the output voltage? What kind of transformer that is, what switching frequency you intend to use? I have to ask, because you are asking questions you should already be aware of, if you intend to make a mains input switching power supply. You generally just buy these so you don't have to make one from scratch, for safety reasons.

Comment: On the output side you have 5V and 5A = 25W.  All these parts need to be sized by that.  Note the average current is 5A but at some point the current is much higher.  The same with voltage.  I don't know enough, but lets say the transformer has a 10:1 turn ration.  So the input current is 1/10 the output current.  The input voltage; 220AC makes about, 360V.  Assuming a flyback PWM the 5V from the output (which is actually 6V because of the diode) makes 50 or 60V on the primary.  So the transistor on the primary sees 360v + 60v + ringing.  The good news is the current is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly answer this question it would be helpful to know more about the 'what and why' of the application. Unless this a learning exercise or you are intending to sell 100,000+ of them, then buying ready made "off the shelf" units is liable to be cheaper and far easier.
Where you are located, how many you wish to make and any cost constraints may affect decisions.

---

As Ron Simpson said in a comment (edited)

> On the output side you have 5V and 5A = 25W.
> All these parts need to be sized based on that.
> Note that the average current is 5A but at some point in the switching cycle the current is much higher.  The same applies to voltage.

In your case rectified mains gives about 160 VDC* and Vout is say 7.5V DC to allow regulation and circuit voltage drops. So average input currents are **ABOUT** 7.5/300 = 1/40th of output current.
That's the average current.
Peak currents will be higher. In this case peak currents will not be vastly higher.  Allowing a 2:1 ratio of Ipeak/Iaverage for input circuitry for *initial* design should be acceptable.

So Iin peak is ~~= 7.5/300 x 5A x 2 ~=  0.25A.

For the input diodes use of low cost 1A diodes suitably rated should be very adequate. The 1N4007 (rated at 1000V, 1A) is commonly used due to price and availability.

The switching transistor should ideally be rated at 600V or more (maybe 500V minimum). A 1A + device should be suitable.

As an **example only** [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IPD50R650CEAUMA1/6599410) 500, 9A MOSFET *may* be suitable.
It is far more capable current wise than required but only about twice the cost of a minimally acceptable device. ($US0.89/1, $0.40/1000)
As above, this is an example only - the actual design needs to be known to allow an acceptable device to be chosen.

A Digi key search [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors/fets-mosfets/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoGwAwA4qgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2uGAJwDstATCMWDfQKzMgAsYt73Lt3bsYnYtwQBmBEmLs41ODC7sGCMHJAjlEebW69VB7k3nUGU6l3gWpQqY7DiQMBrSkuwMWjDD2WHz8VQN8%2BLjAGBXoIhh8GPXB1SThY6gRaRMj0-gipZ0M8gusWfJ08qV4A8Er4EJr4OFo8%2BFYuBjhvS3bOmEce708IzNktPnVqEvAPOmq%2BbjozafgEer5GD2GEd0EWWiUYXfAEODgpJYZ3DubiS8ZwiQzGKbuaC7h2T0SOuu-lDVStyawheiCiLkk9EuPQstC0HVhgJACU6D2RYH%2B8O49Eq7WxBhuPCeYCOlhoina53OLks6kylLp9UstXhjmx1Tiblk7RgfTgR2453STPYGMY7VFam%2Bag%2B0oYdBenz60u4cASEsM7naJ0yTJ1uMeUJpOsQPNGhLiFgyPOowXatH5-nt-Oht0y-JpjA%2BHOoUg8NN9-Au0iiwZkIm12O4eoUUnqUn5ShcCYWVhsqoUiUkYp9vhg8LoPlJCrR8oQvESjHZXEYCiQAF1iAAHAAuUBAAGUWwAnACWADsAOYgAC%2BI9uFBAAFsSLh0PgWwACBRwABuIEbrmQIF7ABN2wBaDGJVvtrgARxbAE924lr038O3MLg0GOgA) of **potentially** suitable parts, ordered by increasing cost in quantity 1.

---

*110 VAC x 1.414 = 155.5V = 160VDC.
I'll not use 100 VAC as many are nominally 110 VAC

Comment: +1, the exact value of transfomer input is not important as the calculation principle is same but how did you get 300 VDC. The formula 2Vm/pi give smaller number.

Comment: @internet Doh !!! :-) Thanks - I'm in NZ. Mains are 230 VAC - I used NZ figure without thinking - even though the question clearly says 100 VAC. || I'll change it to 160V. (110 VAC x 1.414 = 155.5V). I'll not use 100 VAC as many are nominally 110 VAC.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the basics for an isolated flyback converter.  As such, the primary current will indeed be less than the secondary current.  The ratio is not a simple thing to figure, because in a flyback circuit the magnetics are more like coupled inductors than a true transformer.

This is very different from the non-isolated buck converter that Neil refers to.  A buck converter is not recommended for such a large step-down ratio because it makes the primary-side duty cycle very small.  Linear Technology has buck controllers designed specifically for this type of application, but after all of that you still have a non-isolated 5 V source that can be ***very*** dangerous.

There are many flyback design websites.  The most difficult part is the transformer.  If you don't already have a good understanding of what mutual inductance is, you are about to learn.

An alternative is to use a fully-integrated controller and switch, such as the parts from Power Integrations.  They have many reference designs and app notes.  Their parts are so popular that some magnetics companies (Premier - ?) make transformers for some of the more common applications.  If you can find such a fit, that will save you 80% of the overall design effort.